# What files do you need to begin the process of creating a public transportation multimodal network in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, general-transit-feed-specification, multimodal-network

I have never created a multimodal network from scratch before. I want to use General Transit Feed Specification (GTFS).txt files for a New York MTA public transportation network.

What files do I need to begin the process before I even ask about the steps to be performed in QGIS? I already have a lions street file.

Comment: use postgis as a database view with qgis, lots of info on github https://github.com/OpenTransitTools/gtfsdb_realtime